# Gnu sed removes single quotes

Tags: regex, linux, bash, gnu

The problem is that sed removes single quotes besides they are not mentioned in the matching pattern:

```
echo "aaa 'w' ddd" | sed -r 's/aaa/echo dd/ge'
```

results in

```
dd w ddd
```

Do you have any explanation on this?

Answer (score 3):

The "e" at the end is causing it. Essentially, you are asking sed to do this:

```
echo dd 'w' ddd
```

which will produce the results you see. You could do something like this:

```
echo $(echo "aaa 'w' ddd" | sed -e 's/aaa/dd/g')
```

Comment: For better comprehension, I suggest to add a [link to the doc](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) on this special flag.

Comment: `echo $(...)` is redundant

Comment: jkshah: Yes, you are correct. I originally made a 2-step approach with RES=$(echo "aaa 'w' ddd" | sed -e 's/aaa/dd/g'); echo $RES but subsequently decided the OP probably didn't need the result stored in a variable, so I dropped the variable and echoed the result of the $(...) !!!

Comment: I need the extension flag 'e' because it evaluates some arithmetic expressions on the found patterns. Maybe the best way would be to do some preprocessing on the input file and replacing single quotes with \' ? Any other idea?

Comment: Show us what you want to do and we'll have a look! I think Perl may be your friend here...